# Tag Wikis are not properly indicated in the global profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, activity-summary, network-profile

Another re-emergence of an old profile bug in the new stackexchange.com aggregate profile. Tag wiki edits are not listed properly and instead link to nothingness.

[image: I actually didn't realize I made it up to 550 characters on that one...]

As with [what it looks like on the individual profile activity page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74BIf.png), it should list the wiki excerpt and body entries as links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... sort of.

For now we're not actually showing revisions and edits to tag wikis in the global profile.

There was a bug in the "don't try and show those" code, which revealed why its kind of a pain to show those events.

We'll probably be adding those in the "not incredibly distant" future, but for now they're hidden.

Answer (score 2):

To have at least a workaround while the tag-info edits are hidden from the network profile, here are some [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) queries as a possible workaround. (Keep in mind that the database is only updated once a week - so you won't see such edits immediately.)

- A query [listing edits to tag-wikis by the given user on all sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1600140/edits-by-a-specific-users-to-the-tag-wikis-multisite?accountid=267077&Date1=2022-01-01&Date2=2022-07-01). Parameters include the time range - so if the query times out, try to search in a shorter period.
- A similar query [restricted to meta sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1600136/edits-by-a-specific-users-to-the-tag-wikis-only-meta-multisite?accountid=267077).

I have used my own edits as an example - the queries can be used for any user, by changing the parameter accountid.

Of course, if you're interested only in the edits on a single site, the [corresponding query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1600135/edits-by-a-specific-users-to-the-tag-wikis?userid=183484) will be much simpler and less likely to time out.