# Tag wiki edits are missing their title in the user activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, tag-wiki

There's [yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62930/odd-linkless-revisions-appearing-in-my-activity-list) [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86656/tag-wikis-are-not-properly-indicated-in-the-global-profile) minor [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59289/editing-a-tag-wiki-should-show-in-your-activity-log) in the reporting of tag wiki edits in the [user activity tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles?tab=activity): there's no title or link to the edited object.

[image: no tag name or link on a wiki activity log]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a bunch of new post type ids to the `Posts` table yesterday:

```
4  |  Tag Wiki Excerpt
5  |  Tag Wiki 
6  |  Moderator Nomination
7  |  Wiki Placeholder, for FAQ section on SE sites etc... 
8  |  Privilege Wiki, editable on meta
```

Previously they all shared the same post id (3), which cause lots of confusion. The new change makes a lot of code clearer.

Unfortunately, this led to this regression, yet again.

Fixed now

Comment: to be deployed today

Comment: Ack... so PostTypeId = 3 will not exist now? This will break SEDE queries. Could you remap so that tag wikis are 3, then excerpt = 4, nomination = 5, etc.?

Comment: @Jon ... all the past is already remapped now , next data dump will pick it up

Comment: Yeah, what I'm wondering is why the value 3 was not reused for Tag Wikis?

Comment: @Jon cause there are 2 types of tag wikis, now I know that 3 means orphan wiki and stuff that we failed to map. it helps me find errors

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough. Thanks for the explanation.