# Missing link and caption in review activity description for Tag Wiki edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

The `reviews` tab of user activity show the suggested edits approved or rejected by that user with link to the suggested edit itself plus link to the post being edited.

All good with questions and answers, but for tag wiki edit the link to the post being edited (in this case the tag info page) is missing:
[image: missing link screenshot]

The first blank line should point for example to:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/terracotta/info
With caption like *terracotta tag wiki*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, fixed now. Left over from when I changed the post type id for tag wikis.

[Tag wiki edits are missing their title in the user activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93348/tag-wiki-edits-are-missing-their-title-in-the-user-activity-tab/93351#93351)