# Reputation gain for tag wiki edits are missing title and link in the achievements dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Entries for tag wiki edits in the new achievements dropdown only show +2 and don't link anywhere. Both the excerpt and tag wiki itself are affected.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: also repro in IE11

Comment: [Non-repo on Meta.SO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H08Z8.png)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That's a suggested edit, not a **tag wiki edit**.

Comment: ohh, right. I believe I should try that as well.

Comment: Same in Firefox. Did it yesterday, didn't notice until checking after reading this :-) That's two separate Suggestions, on `tag wiki` and `tag wiki excerpt`, for mine anyway.

Comment: Maybe new incarnation of [this old, fixed, bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95873/152859)?

Comment: [Does affect tag-wiki-edits on Mata.SO as well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RTQqC.png) - [Review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22295)

Comment: But the link to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/top-bar/info is there.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn for me the "links" are just empty `<a>` tags with no attributes

Comment: My link has a `href`. I use FF 25.0.1. The tag wiki was on MSO.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in the next build, the non-post items will have proper descriptions and links.